# Adding a control to Cells of a datagridview column

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Just a quick question about adding a control to a Datagridview cell when the user clicks it. I want to add either a button or an open dialog button to a cell once the user clicks it. I have the column headers populated from a string array and the rows populated with another. I found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92) on hosting controls in a datagridview cell but I'm confused by it as it adds a datetimepicker whereas I only want a open dialog button or regular button. Is there any other good informative articles online? I did research it but couldnt find muc...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Accept more answers to your questions

Comment: apologies I actually was in the process of going back over those old posts

Comment: What might be a simpler is to use the out of the box DataGridViewButton column and then disable the button when your conditions are not met. (You can also hide buttons but that is a bit more hacky)